# White space below footer caused by javascript... how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have an annoying white space below footer problem, and no matter how long I have searched for the answer I cannot find it, because it doesn't seem to be anything I can do in CSS to solve the problem. Also, the problem is not on every page... it arbitrarily selects (seemingly) random pages within the website, which made me think that perhaps it is happening as a result of some javascript code that I cannot seem to locate as being the offending party.

Anyway, after hours of scrolling through websites, I decided to load the website without javascript and sure enough the white space disappeared. As a somewhat novice programmer, I'm not really sure what to do next. I put

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

right before  in my header, and voila, it worked... no more white space on any of the pages. So technically, I guess this resolves my problem, at least visually, but since I'm a novice, I have no idea what the potential repercussions are for this? Is it okay to leave it? Could I try something else? Does this problem sound familiar to anyone? Many thanks in advance for your help! I don't know if you'll need more info than this.

Just to be clear, I'm developing a child theme in Wordpress off of someone else's theme. The website is a multisite, and the other site on the multisite doesn't seem to be broken at all, despite having nearly all the same elements. One of the few differences is a Contact Form 7 form where they each have their own instance of a CF7 form. When I attempted to add some javascript to the CF7 form, I believe that's when it broke. Since I only added it to one website (within the form itself), I think that's why only one website broke with the white space underneath. Simply removing the code wasn't enough.

By the way, I should add I have had this problem with this website before, and my (weird) solution at that time was to rename the links of the pages where the white gap was showing up... and sure enough, it worked. Obviously, as my site grows backlinks I don't want to keep doing that.

So, is my rudimentary fix enough?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing any of your actual code.  Show an example of what you think is causing the problem and specifically what you've tried to correct it.

Comment: We would need more information to know for sure. The little bit of code you gave us doesn't tell us anything. The "clear" class could have anything applied to it, but most likely it is a "clearfix" div which is used in floated layouts, generally to resolve issues with floated elements having a height of 0.

Comment: Thanks guys - I guess what I'm saying is, what is the danger of putting something before my <!DOCTYPE> declaration? After all, should that not be the very first thing in my html document? And if it's not, will this hurt things like SEO or Google page rankings?

Comment: "The <!DOCTYPE> declaration must be the very first thing in your HTML document, before the <html> tag.": http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DOCTYPE.asp

Comment: [The doctype explains what type of HTML is to be expected and therefore what spec validators (for example the W3C HTML validator) should validate your document against.](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Doctypes_and_markup_styles)

Comment: @user2991456 you should throw your comment clearing up the questioning in the actual question.

Comment: CSS: .clear {clear: both;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is resolved (as of right now). The problem was a plugin conflict that was writing javascript to the footer. It only caused a problem when I added javascript to the Contact Form 7 plugin.

To resolve the issue, I edited the HTML in firebug as you suggested, Alex. Once I found out the offending plugin I disabled the conflicting scripts.

Thanks for all your help, guys. This is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

As APAD1 said, the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration must always be the very first element in the HTML document, otherwise it will have no effect!  The fact that placing `<div class="clear"></div>` before the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration seemed to fix your problem indicates that the white-space was somehow the related to or caused by the browser defaults for that particular HTML rendering mode.

Also, what browser are you using?  You're not using Internet Explorer, are you?  Different browsers or even different versions of the same browser may render your page differently.

As for the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration, it is needed to indicate a particular layout mode the browser should enter.

In Internet Explorer, for example, the omission of a `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration may cause the browser to enter *Quirks mode*, as opposed to a *Standards-Compliance mode*.  Note that `<!DOCTYPE html>` is used for HTML5 documents, whereas something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`
```

...is used for HTML4.  The (X)HTML doctype declaration is used to put the browser into a particular layout/rendering mode.  Different rendering modes result in different CSS default styles.  It is likely that some combination of CSS rules are resulting in the unexpected white-space.

I suggest you become familiar with (or at least play around with) [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) (a FireFox extension), the [Webkit Inspector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29#Features) ("Developer Tools") that comes in Google Chrome and Safari, and/or the [IE Developer Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Developer_Tools).  All of these tools allow you to "inspect" elements in the [Document Object Model (DOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) for your webpage.  These tools will even let you view and modify the HTML source code and CSS rules for elements in the DOM.  (Please be aware any changes you make with these tools will not be saved and therefore are *not* persistent!)  This means that using one of these tools, you can select your footer element and view its applied ("computed") CSS styles.  This is especially helpful in not only troubleshooting your webpage or WordPress theme, but also in developing it.

So, to sum up:

- If you don't place the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration as the first element, then you might as well omit it altogether.
- The `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration places the browser in a particular layout mode that has certain CSS defaults.
- A combination of CSS rules is likely resulting in the unexpected white-space.
- You may use browser "developer tools" such as FireBug to inspect (and modify) your webpage.

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks Alex. Although I have been using Firebug on working every CSS combination I can see that could possibly affect the element. What I know is this:

(1) it is being affected within either the body or the html tags, or possibly both. (2) it is definitely javascript related (3) it has shown up on every browser and screen size I have tried (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, mobile phone, ipad... everything...) (4) while the overflow shows up in the footer, if I put a period sign before the doctype declaration, the white space will move to the top and ignore the bottom.